# Google+ api for flex air mobile

Tags: apache-flex, google-plus, flex4.6

I am new in flex air mobile application and this is my first project. I want to know about google+ api for flex air mobile. Any documentation or tutorial available for this? Its urgent.

Answer (score 0):

I checked in the [Google+ API](http://flex-arulmurugant.blogspot.in/2011/09/flex-google-api-and-actionscript-3.html). I found [this implementation example](http://flex-arulmurugant.blogspot.in/2011/09/flex-google-api-and-actionscript-3.html) of flex using Google+ API.  I am still to find some detailed native support given by Google like they have for [Flex for maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/tutorial-flex).

Comment: Google maps for Flash/Flex are obsolete.

Comment: Yes, that is true... the site reads The Google Maps API for Flash has been officially deprecated as of September 2, 2011. May be that is the exact reason why they are not providing Flex support for Google+. They want to keep JavaScript/JSON as their standard API.

Comment: Here is an alternative in DevGirl blog: http://devgirl.org/2011/12/06/flex-mobile-development-adding-maps-with-mapquest-flash-api-w-sample-app/

Comment: Actually he is not looking for maps, I gave Maps as an example only. He wants Google+ API for Adobe Flex.

Comment: My point is that since Google dropped support for the Flex/Flash maps, they probably won't introduce any Flex/Flash support for Google+ API. So you have to workaround with StageWebView/ExternalInterface etc. like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717919/how-to-integrate-google-in-a-flex-mobile-application/10733009